# Adding a count to object array in python

Tags: python

How would you count and group object array using `Counter`

```py
list = [ {
            "text": "London",
        },
        {
            "text": "New york",
        },
        {
            "text": "London",
        }]
```

The output that im expecting is:

```
[ {
      "text": "London",
      "count": 2
  },
  {
      "text": "New york",
      "count": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a more compact option you can do this with a one line list comprehension

```
lst = [ {
            "text": "London",
        },
        {
            "text": "New york",
        },
        {
            "text": "London",
        }]


[{'text': location, 'count': [x['text'] for x in lst].count(location)} for location in set([x['text'] for x in lst])]
```

Output:

```
 [{'text': 'London', 'count': 2}, {'text': 'New york', 'count': 1}]
```

Note: I renamed the original list just to avoid using the keyword list as a variable name

To extend this for an arbitrary number of attributes that are unique to the location use this

```
[{**{n['text']: n for n in lst}[loc], **{'count': [x['text'] for x in lst].count(loc)}} for loc in set([x['text'] for x in lst])]
```

with a new input of

```
lst = [ {
            "text": "London",
            "country": "UK"
        },
        {
            "text": "New york",
            "country": "USA"
        },
        {
            "text": "London",
            "country": "UK"
        }]
```

Output:

```
[{'text': 'New york', 'country': 'USA', 'count': 1},
 {'text': 'London', 'country': 'UK', 'count': 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks how would you make it reusable so when you have more properties other then "text" they will be added to the built array? thanks

Comment: would the other properties be unique to the location or would you need to separate several instances of each location based on other properties?

Comment: they are unique. thankls

Answer (score 2):

An option would be the following:

```
counter = {}

for d in current_list:
    for v in d.values():
        present = counter.get(v)
        if present:
            counter[v] += 1
        else:
            counter[v] = 1
print(counter)

new_dict = [{"text": k, "counter": v} for k, v in counter.items()]
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: More readable than the accepted answer, in my opinion.  Though `new_dict` looks as though it's actually a list `[]` so name is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Unserious `itertools.groupby` solution

```
from itertools import groupby


L = [ {
            "text": "London",
        },
        {
            "text": "New york",
        },
        {
            "text": "London",
        }]

L = [{**key, "count" : len((*group,))} for key, group in groupby(sorted(L, key=str))]

print(L)
```

It works in this case because the dictionaries have only a key, but it might not work if you have 2 dictionaries with keys ordered in opposite ways, happy to improve it if you have any suggestion for the sorting function

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two steps

```py
from collections import Counter

>>> l = [...]

>>> counter = Counter([x['text'] for x in l])
>>> [{'text': k, 'count': c} for k, c in counter.items()]

[{'text': 'London', 'count': 2}, {'text': 'New york', 'count': 1}]
```